# jQuery synchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery

For rendering a dialog, i have two jQuery ajax calls. One to load the buttons and another to load the body of the dialog. I first call the function that loads the buttons (asychronous ajax call)

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //async: false,
    url: action,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        $('#dialogButtons').html(result);         
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(req + " " + error + " " + status);
    }
```

Then i call another similar ajax call to load the body of the dialog in asychronous fashion.

The buttons doesn't always show up. So I made

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

$.ajax({
   asyc: false,
   url: action 
})

$.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

as per other stack overflow experts. i am seeing mixed opinions on this approach.

Please help me with the standard way to achieve this.

Comment: makes no sense to do ` $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });` and the true one...

Comment: I assume you do not have the typo `asyc: false,`

Comment: async false vs true is irrelevant to whether or not buttons show up. async: false should simply never be used.

Comment: Never use synchronous ajax. You can start a second call from inside success if you need chaining. But you can also do it in parallel. Or even better try async/await if you can.

Comment: you can synchronize async functions with callback or promises you should look up for that, sync calls are blocking the ui and thats not a good approach

Comment: I had looked at jquery .then() but it is not available in the jquery version that I am using and compatible jQuery-ui. 
I quickly looked at the async/await, is it the way to go? 
Can you please give me head start for callback or promise?

Comment: @Programmer which jQuery version are you using? The simplest could be something like this: `$.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function (result) {
        /*do some stuff*/
        $.ajax({..., success: function (result) {/*do other stuff*/}})         
    },`

Comment: Why are you using `dataType: 'json'` if it returns HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Do the second AJAX call in the `success` function of the first.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: action,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(result) {
    $('#dialogButtons').html(result).hide(); // Will show it after 2nd AJAX call
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      url: otheraction,
      success: function(result) {
        if (result) {
          $("#dialog").html(result);
          $("#dialogButtons").show();
        }
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(req, status, error) {
    alert(req + " " + error + " " + status);
  }
});
```

You also shouldn't have `contentType: "application/json"`. You're not sending any post data, and `$.ajax` doesn't send JSON; if you had post data, it would be URL-encoded.

Comment: The key challenge is depending on the whether data is returned or not from the second ajax call for the body of the dialog, the buttons needs to be hidden which is still asynchronously in progress. And this is across the application for all the dialogs and buttons. So i need a generic way to achieve this in jQuery

Comment: The second AJAX call isn't performed until after the first one is completed, it's not "still asynchronously in progress".

Comment: I've added code showing how you can show the buttons conditionally on whether the 2nd AJAX call returns something.